# How can I get links from a certain class on a website with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am making a program that will download a game from a website with some user input and a Microsoft edge webdriver.
I need to get a few specific links from classes with a common name, but I don't know how to.
I highly appreciate your help.
This is the website I'm getting my links from (The links are in the class called "blog-post") :
https://steamunlocked.net/?s=Minecraft
This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Make a window
root = Tk()
#Functions
def ree():
    browser = webdriver.Edge(executable_path="C:\\Users\\srish\\Documents\\Code 
    Projects\\Selenium\\msedgedriver.exe")
    browser.get('https://www.steamunlocked.net')
    element = browser.find_element_by_id("s")
    element.send_keys(game.get())
    element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    for a in browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
# Tkinter window body
game = Entry(root)
game.pack()
games = Button(root, text="Search for games!", command=ree)
games.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `xpath` to get links for games

```
find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="blog-content"]//a/@href')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath to get list of href tags

```
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//body//div[@id='main_wrapper']//div//div//div//div[*]//div[1]//h2[1]//a")))
            
for element in elements:
               print element.text
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```